# Class file creation concepts

Tags: java, class, jar

I tried a strange experiment.
I created a project in Eclipse. I created Abc.java which has a main method which prints "Hello" to output.
I then built the project using eclipse. A class file named Abc.class was created. I copied that class file to some random location. Then , I navigated to the class file and used the following command to execute it.

```
java Abc
```

It printed "Hello" on the console. So far so well. I assume for a simple sysout there are no dependencies a JVM needs to resolve.

Next I created a very complex program in my eclipse for which I had to include 15 different jars(ex slf4j and apache-commons). After building the program in eclipse, I just copied its class files to a different location(not the JARS). 
The main method which does all the complex coding was still in Abc.

I hit the command again(this time I followed package structure so I had to call a slightly different command).

```
java com.great.Abc
```

I was under the impression that since I hadn't added any jars to classpath in the java command, this code would break down miserably(remember it had a lot of dependencies).
However, its working absolutely fine.

Can someone please explain why?

---

(Half hour later :|)
Meanwhile I tried another experiment, and this amazes me even more. I mailed all the class files generated through eclipse to a different computer (note that I did not mail the jar files, only the class files generated by eclipse).

And I ran the program over there, hoping that it would break this time.
And guess what, it runs perfectly. Any inputs?

Are the jars required only at compile time?
How would I ensure that the jars I use are needed at runtime while creating a program?
Please explain calmly no matter how stupid the questions seem. :)

Comment: what way that you build the project?

Comment: If your `com.great.Abc` class does not import those dependencies, then it should run fine.

Comment: com.great.Abc does not import those dependencies, however it uses other class files in the same package (has a relationship). These other class files use those dependencies. Is everything alright?

Comment: @DipanshuVerma: Even though the other files import the dependencies, do they actually *use* them? Do they actually create instances of classes defined therein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, code dependencies are established between *classes* so when you create a class which just prints a message, your eclipse project setup has no relevance as long as your class is not using any class from the fancy eclipse setup.

Even if your class is referring to other classes it might happen that these classes are not loaded at runtime when the class is not really using them.

Even if you launch a Java program from a jar file which has dependencies to other jar files declared in its manifest, the standard Java launcher will ignore the absence of one or more of these jar files silently and during the program execution it will report failures only if required classes from these missing jar were tried to load.

One case were it is guaranteed that your program will break early is when its superclass is not present at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The Jar files aside, I actually find it strange enough that it even loaded your `Abc` class itself, since the JVM would look for `com.great.Abc` only in a `com/great` subdirectory of your classpath. I suspect that you, somehow, have some implicit classpath set in your environment or something, which points back to your Eclipse environment, and that the JVM found it there.

To verify this being or not being the case, you can run Java with the `-verbose:class` option, to make it tell you where it loads classes from:

```
java -verbose:class com.great.Abc
```

Comment: the first class file did not have any packaging, the second class was a different Abc packaged properly, so that answers your first query. I am looking into the second one:)

Comment: @DipanshuVerma: That was precisely what I meant, though. Since the first one had no package, it is not strange that the JVM found it. Since the second one had a package, it is strange that the JVM found it.

Comment: Without an explicit class path, Java will load from the current directory.

Comment: @Holger: Yes, of course, but loading a class from an explicit package will still look in a subdirectory of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses the Absolute path to your included jar files.
Even when you move your main class it still works fine

Comment: A simple class-file does not include any form of classpath at all, however.